# python path set up for sub packages in centos machine

Tags: python-2.7

I have default python installed in Linux machine.

I have to add the additional sub-packages to the python path so that when I try to import the packages from python console, it should directly go to the directory where the packages installed and import from there.

I tried to add that directory path to the `PYTHONPATH` through `.bash_profile`, but there is no variable `PYTHONPATH` there?

How should I add that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let edit the `.bash_profile` file with the line:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/the/folder
```

It is nevertheless safer to write:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/the/folder:$PYTHONPATH
```

If something modifies it before. Note that you can do it in the `bash` terminal before running `python`

Comment: Thanks @xiawi, Since i am new to Unix Machines, I was bit confused while setting the path variables. Thanks for your help